# how can i use foreach to get value and name php

Tags: php

i want to get value of this variable :

```
$File = new FileFromDB($_GET['filename']);
```

by trying this code :

```
foreach($File as $key => $name){
     print_r( "$key => $name");
}
```

but it dont work , when i print $file it show

> FileFromDB Object ( [filename:FileFromDB:private] => tp4.php )

pliz help me how can i get only 'tp4.php' without all this syntaxe.

Comment: What is the structure of your `$File` object?  Instead of all this `foreach` stuff, just do `print_r($File)` and add the output to your question.

Comment: You must make a difference between an _array_ and an _object_. Both hold things within, but they still are a different thing!

Comment: print_r($File) show FileFromDB Object ( [filename:FileFromDB:private] => tp4.php )

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is clearly described in PHP Manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$file` is an object from type `FileFromDB`. `filename` is a private(!) property of that object. (Your var dump shows this).

To access the filename, `FileFromDB` needs to provide a public method to access the property:

```
class FileFromDB

    ...

    public function getFilename() {
        return $this->filename;
    }

    ...

}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$file = new FileFromDB($_GET['filename']);
$filename = $file->getFilename();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want tp4.php just do it like this:

```
foreach($File as $key => $name){

    echo $name;

}
```

Comment: And this will output a ton of other stuff - everything inside the `$File` object.

Comment: Yeah I just saw $File isn't even an array so no need to even loop through it. Look at hek2mgl's answer.